# Image is not changing even i changed image

Tags: angularjs

In angularjs if i change or remove image it does not make any changes. After refreshing the page it show the changed image.I am using following line to remove image

**jQuery**

```
$('#profile_image').val('')
```

Comment: so why you using angular when you already want to do this by `jquery`?

Comment: ok fine but how can i do it from angular?

Comment: Hi, What is the format of the image you are displaying? Url or Base64??

Comment: Hi,Actually i am inserting image path in database and store image in folder.from that folder i am showing that corresponding image by mysql query.I really donot konow what is URL or basse64 image format

Answer (score 0):

> This Sample is basic if you want to know more about **[AngularJs](https://angularjs.org/)** click on link

```js
var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.controller("ctrl", [
  "$scope",
  function($scope) {
    $scope.imgShow = true;
    $scope.imgSrc = "https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/75025ad9a8cfdaa5772545e6e8f41133?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1";

    $scope.display = function() {
      $scope.imgShow = true;
      $scope.imgSrc = "https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/75025ad9a8cfdaa5772545e6e8f41133?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1";
    }

    $scope.change = function() {
      $scope.imgSrc = "https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/fccd71b79b3571b459cdfe40e7bf5dd8?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1";
    }

    $scope.remove = function() {
      $scope.imgShow = false;
    }

  }
]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <img ng-src="{{imgSrc}}" ng-show="imgShow">
  <hr/>
  <button ng-click="display()" ng-hide="imgShow">display image</button>
  <button ng-click="change()">change image</button>
  <button ng-click="remove()">remove image</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Actually i am using <input type="file"> to add user defined image.when i want to remove image i am using <span class="fileupload-exists" onclick="$('#profile_image').click()">Change</span> when i want to add image <input valid-file class="upload" type="file" name="profile_image" id="profile_image" ng-model="text.profile_image" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().photoChanged(this.files)" />

Comment: @Vivekvetrri Do not use angular.element(this).scope() since it will not work in case you'll disable debug info for production, as recommended in the docs. .scope() method should be used only for testing/debugging.

Comment: @Vivekvetrri Please update the question about `<input type="file">` usage, since the question is not formed well.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to manipulate the DOM in AngularJS you should use [directives for this purpose](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive).

You should avoid using `jquery` inside of your controllers and simply work with your model. Below is `fileUpload` directive that could help you to work with `<input type="file">` in a more angularjs-way:

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('TestController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    var ctrl = this;
    
    ctrl.imageFile = null;
    ctrl.clearFile = clearFile;
    
    function clearFile(){
      ctrl.imageFile = null;
    }
    
    $scope.$ctrl = ctrl;
}])
.directive('fileUpload', [function () {
  return {
    require: "ngModel",
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function ($scope, el, attrs, ngModel) {
      function onChange (event) {
        //update bindings with $applyAsync
        $scope.$applyAsync(function(){
          ngModel.$setViewValue(event.target.files[0]);
        });
      }
      //change event handler
      el.on('change', onChange);
      
      //set up a $watch for the ngModel.$viewValue
      $scope.$watch(function () {
        return ngModel.$viewValue;
      }, function (value) {
        //clear input value if model was cleared
        if (!value) {
          el.val("");
        }
      });
      //remove change event handler on $destroy
      $scope.$on('$destroy', function(){
        el.off('change', onChange);
      });
    }
  };
}]);
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.angularjs.org/1.3.20/angular.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="TestController">
    <input type="file" file-upload ng-model="$ctrl.imageFile" />
    <input type="button" ng-click="$ctrl.clearFile()" value="Reset" />
    <div ng-if="$ctrl.imageFile">
      {{$ctrl.imageFile.name}}<br />
      {{$ctrl.imageFile.size}} byte(s)<br/>
      {{$ctrl.imageFile.type}}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**UPDATE:** Also take a look at [this useful reading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/thinking-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background).

Comment: @Vivekvetrri was this helpful for you?