# How to clear form input after uploading file on s3 bucket in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, meteor, angularjs-directive

A form is not getting clear after uploading a file.

```
  <div class="aboutFile">
     <input type="file" name="file" fileread="vm.file" class="form-control" ng-model="vm.file">
        <div class="create-component--perma-bg">
            <i class="fa fa-plus-square-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <span ng-if="!vm.file.name">Add File </span>
            <span ng-if="vm.file.name">{{vm.file.name}}</span>
        </div>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-info bgChangeBtnInfo" ng-
           click="vm.upload(vm.file)" ng-disabled="!vm.file"> Upload</button>
       </div>
```

`vm.upload` method called.

```
    vm.upload = (fileObj) =>{
        vm.call("saveSlideFile", vm.slideObject, (error, result) => {
          if (!error) {
           vm.file={};
           console.log('File saved successfully');
          }
       })
  }
```

`fileread` directive

```
angular.module('livePoll')
    .directive("fileread", [function () {
        return {
            scope: {
                fileread: "="
            },
            link: function(scope,element, attributes){
                $('.button-collapse').sideNav();
                element.bind("change", function (event) {
                    scope.$apply(function () {
                        scope.fileread = event.target.files[0];
                        scope.$parent.fileread = scope.fileread;
                    });
                })
            }};
    }]
```

Comment: Your directive is changing the model only on `change` event, but doesn't clear the field when the model changes from the parent controller. Take a look at [this answer and possible directive implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44517492/4222181).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this problem with just one line of code with the help of amazing Tech website i.e. [Technoalerts](https://www.technoalerts.com/). Thanks guys for the help and I'll share this info with you all.

**Just follow the steps mentioned below:-**

In input form, we have to assign the id.

```
 <input type="file" name="file" fileread="vm.file" class="form-control" id="inputFile" ng-model="vm.file">
```

In this Where `vm.upload` method is called there i used  `$('#inputFile').val('');` for clearing a form field after performing any action.

`vm.upload`

```
 vm.upload = (fileObj) =>{
    vm.call("saveSlideFile", vm.slideObject, (error, result) => {
      if (!error) {
       $('#inputFile')
       vm.file={};
       console.log('File saved successfully');
      }
   })
}
```

Comment: Manipulating DOM in controller [is not a good practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29981419/angularjs-why-manipulating-dom-in-controller-is-a-bad-thing). Why just not do this in the `directive`?

Answer (score 2):

1) Avoid using `scope.$parent.fileread = scope.fileread;` this [code smells](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell), doesn't make any sense since you are using `=` binding and could lead to unpredictable behavior.

2) In case you are using `ngModel`, you can avoid using bindings in your directive and use [`NgModelController.$setViewValue`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController#$setViewValue) to update the view value like:

```
function onChange (event) {
  //update bindings in $apply block
  $scope.$apply(function(){
    ngModel.$setViewValue(event.target.files[0]);
  });
}
//change event handler
element.on('change', onChange);
```

3) You can set up a [`$watch`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watch) on [`NgModelController.$viewValue`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController#$viewValue) inside your directive and clear the input field, when the value was changed in parent:

```
//set up a $watch for the ngModel.$viewValue
$scope.$watch(function () {
  return ngModel.$viewValue;
}, function (value) {
  //clear input value if model was cleared
  if (!value) {
    element.val("");
  }
});
```